# Implicit conversion of string literals

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc

Earlier today I tried to compile code similar to:

```
class example
{
public:
    example(const char (&in_data)[6]);
};

example foo()
{
    return "ABCDE";
}
```

On GCC, and it complained about there being no conversion to example on the return line. I was able to initialize objects of type example in other places with code such as

```
example bar("ABCDE");
```

just fine. All this worked fine when compiled in VS2010 as well.

Now, my question is, should this have worked, or is this some visual studio compiler extension? It seems to me that this *should* work due to the non-explicit constructor...

I don't have the exact error message right now because I'm not at work, but it's really bothering me.

Comment: `const char (&in_data)[6]`... eww...

Comment: The constructor is `private` and there is a semicolon missing after `example`. Which other details did you leave out that may affect the answer?

Comment: I wanted a compile-time error if a string-literal of the wrong length was passed in.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl, hence the 'similar to'. Yes, this isn't the actual code.

Comment: @Bwmat1: So you couldn't create something like [this](http://ideone.com/pax6CH)?

Comment: To see the problem in action: http://ideone.com/J1QMFo @DietmarKühl I see we had the same idea, but I added the version that works as well.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, AFAIK, the type of a string literal n characters long is actually const char[n+1] in C++, not const char*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any reason why the implicit conversion shouldn't work. Trying with gcc, clang, and EDG, only gcc fails. I'd *guess* this is a gcc error. That said, gcc seems to be keen to create a `char const*` out of an array reference. This code

```
example f()
{
    char const (&array)[6] = "abcde";
    return array;
}
```

yields this error:

```
implicit.cpp: In function ‘example f()’:
implicit.cpp:10:12: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)array’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘example’
     return array;
            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the constructor of the example class, instead of just declaring it? The constructor is important if you'd like to use implicit conversion, I think.

Comment: When I came across the issue, I did have the constructor defined as well, but even if I hadn't that would have been a linker error rather than a compilation error.